# mysql how to compare strings and return rows between two strings

Tags: mysql, string-comparison

How can I simply filter a table row by alphabets for example showing only rows with strings starting with `e`,`f` and `g` and exclude other rows.

Something like

```
return (rows > "d") andalso (rows < "h")
```

in `vb.net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `like` if you want regular expression. for example, this will give you all rows starting with `a`:

```
select * from myTable where myColumn like 'a%';
```

EDIT:

I see what you mean now, mysql supports > and < for strings as well, so if you do:

```
where col >= 'e' and col < 'h'
```

you will essentially get everything starting by e,f,g

Comment: and what about b c d... I want something to compare like < or > in vb.net for example all `rows < h and rows > d`

Comment: @idealidea - see my edit, I think I understand your question better now

Comment: Oh now I see, but I was thinking of using `like` someway I didn't know its possible simply by operators >= and <, and as I remember only `like` was strings comparing solution in mysql. Thanks anyway. This works.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple `LIKE` operator saying

```
select * from table1
where mycol like 'e%'
or mycol like 'f%'
or mycol like 'g%';
```

(OR) you can use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) string function saying

```
select * from table1
where left(mycol,1) in ('e','f','g');
```